# Convert JSON dict in Bash to Powershell

Tags: json, bash, powershell

I need some help passing this json dict to the variable `RESPONSE`. But I am unsure how to convert this to powershell from bash.
I tried using piping to `| ConvertTo-Json -Compress` but couldn't quite get it right

```
RESPONSE="$(cat <<EOT
{
  "spec": {
    "instance": "$NODENAME",
    "hostname": true,
    "container": [
      {
        "seccontent": {
          "objectA": true
        },
        "image": "$IMAGENAME",
        "command": [ "tester", "--target", "1", "--mount", "--test", "--test", "--net", "--pid", "--", "bash", "-l" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
EOT
)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multiple lines string like this:

```
> $RESPONSE=@'
{
  "spec": {
    "instance": "$NODENAME",
    "hostname": true,
    "container": [
      {
        "seccontent": {
          "objectA": true
        },
        "image": "$IMAGENAME",
        "command": [ "nsenter", "--target", "1", "--mount", "--uts", "--ipc", "--net", "--pid", "--", "bash", "-l" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
'@
```

And, then convert to JSON:

```bsh
> $RESPONSE | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!